# Trying to create procedure in snowflake and getting error while passing value to another procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below procedure to get the value from the metadata table and pass
its value into another procedure.

```
create or replace procedure get_results()
     RETURNS VARIANT
     LANGUAGE javascript
    as
    $$
    var return_value = [];
    var SQL_STMT = "select * from metad" ;
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
           {
           sqlText: SQL_STMT
           }
        );
    /* Creates result set */
    var res = stmt.execute();
    while (res.next())  {
        //return_value += "\n";
        var srctbl=res.getColumnValue('SRC_TBL');
        var tgttbl=res.getColumnValue('TGT_TBL'); 
        var prc_stmt = 'CALL sync_table('+ srctbl + ',' + tgttbl+')';
        var pstmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: prc_stmt});
         /* Creates result set */
        var spResult = pstmt.execute();
        if(spResult !='Success'){
        return_value=spResult;
        break;
        }
        }
            
    return return_value;
    $$
    ;
```

```
CALL get_results()
```

Give the error message:

> Execution error in store procedure GET_RESULTS: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 16 invalid indetifier 'STBL1' At Statement.execute, line 18 position 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess that both the values you are passing to the Stored Procedure `sync_table` are strings, and you sql command `prc_stmt` will look like:

```
CALL sync_table( soruce_table_name, target_table_name );
```

but that is not valid SQL, it should be

```
CALL sync_table( 'soruce_table_name', 'target_table_name' );
```

which means you should add some quotes, given this is javascript the string can use double quotes and allow simple insertion of the needed single quotes:

```
create or replace procedure get_results()
     RETURNS VARIANT
     LANGUAGE javascript
    as
    $$
    var return_value = [];
    var SQL_STMT = "select * from metad" ;
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
           {
           sqlText: SQL_STMT
           }
        );
    /* Creates result set */
    var res = stmt.execute();
    while (res.next())  {
        //return_value += "\n";
        var srctbl=res.getColumnValue('SRC_TBL');
        var tgttbl=res.getColumnValue('TGT_TBL'); 
        var prc_stmt = "CALL sync_table('"+ srctbl + "','" + tgttbl+"')";
        var pstmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: prc_stmt});
         /* Creates result set */
        var spResult = pstmt.execute();
        if(spResult !='Success'){
            return_value=spResult;
            break;
        }
    }
            
    return return_value;
    $$
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks, @simeon-pilgrim for the prompt response I am able to solve it now. i have same string here can you please confirm if I did it right.   var spSommand='Call ' + DB_NAME + ',' + SCHEMA_NAME + '.proc('"+PRM1+"','"+PRM1+"','"+PRM1+"','"+PRM1+"','"+PRM1+"','"+PRM1+"')'

Comment: after you build `prc_stmt` assign it to your `return_value` and the break, and you should get your SQL given back to you. Then try run it. If it runs, you good to go onto the next step. But how that is written your have not matched it correctly.

Comment: `var spSommand="Call " + DB_NAME + "." + SCHEMA_NAME + ".proc('"+PRM1 + "','" + PRM1 + "','" + PRM1 + "','" + PRM1 + "','" + PRM1 + "','" + PRM1 + "')";`

Comment: Will it give output like 


"CALL DB.SCHEMA.PROC('PRM1','PRM1','PRM1','PRM1','PRM1','PRM1','PRM1')"

Comment: That what you are want to produce, it's just basic Javascript string concatenation, you can even test your code in you web browser JS console.